# Rename Files to original extensions

Tags: bash

Need help on writing a bash script that will rename files that are being outputted as file name.suffix.date I need these files to be rewritten as name.date.suffix instead.

Edited:
Changed suffix from date to ~
Here's what I have so far:

```
find . -type f -name "*.~" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f
do
   new=`echo "$f" | sed -e "s/~//"`
   mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

This changes the suffix back to original but can't figure out how to get the date to be named before the extension (fname??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression matching to pull apart the original file name:

```
find . -type f -name "*.~" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f
do
   dir=${f%/*}
   fname=${f##*/}
   [[ $fname =~ (.+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.~$ ]] || continue
   name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
   suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
   d=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

   mv "$f" "$dir/$name.$d.$suffix" 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash-only solution:

```
while IFS=. read -r -u 9 -d '' name suffix date tilde
do
    mv "${name}.${suffix}.${date}.~" "${name}.${date}.${suffix}"
done 9< <(find . -type f -name "*.~" -print0)
```

Notes:

- `-d ''` gives you the same result as `-d $'\0'`
- Splits file names by the dots while reading them. Of course this means it would break if there are dots anywhere else.
- Should otherwise work with pretty much any filenames, including those containing space, newlines and other funny business.

Comment: This assumes that `name` will not contain a `.`.

Comment: Yes, it's in the notes part.

Comment: i am getting files named as "test2.txt.20130320 95325.~" noww instead of the original "test2.txt.20130320.~" ??

Comment: @jmituzas You need to be more precise. What is the full name of the original file? If it really contains a tilde character instead of a date, you need to update your question. And what do you mean by "getting files"? I guarantee you this code does not rename `test2.txt.20130320.~` to `test2.txt.20130320 95325.~` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a list of the files first and redirect to a file.
   ls > fileList.txt
2. Open the file and read line by line in Perl. Use a regex to match the parts of the files and capture them like  this

   `my ($fileName,$suffix,$date)=($WholeFileName=~/(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)/);`

   This should capture the three seperate variables for you. Now all you need to do is move the old file to the new file name. The new file name will be a concatenation of the above three variables that you have got. $newFileName=$fileName. ".".$date.".".$suffix. If you have a sample fileName post a comment and I can reply with a short script. Perl is not the only way. You could just use bash or awk and find alternate ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. cut each part of your filenames:

   ```
   FIN=$(echo test.12345.ABCDEF | sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\\.][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\\.]//')
   DEBUT=$(echo test.12345.ABCDEF | sed -e 's/[\\.][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\\.][a-zA-Z0-9]*//')
   MILIEU=$(echo test.12345.ABCDEF | sed -e 's/'${FIN}'//' -e 's/'${DEBUT}'//' -e 's/[\.]*//g')
   ```
2. paste each part as expected:

   ```
   echo ${DEBUT}.${FIN}.${MILIEU}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
rename --no-act 's/\(name-regex\).\(suffix-regex\).\(date-regex\)/\1.\3.\2' *
```

Tweak the three regexes to fit your file names, and remove `--no-act` when you're happy with the result to actually rename the files.